# Is it normal for a COMPLETED Spring Batch job to to start again?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

According to Spring batch JobOperator class's `restart(executionId)` documentation,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.html#restart-long-

> Restart a failed or stopped JobExecution. Fails with an exception if the id provided does not exist or corresponds to a JobInstance that in normal circumstances already completed successfully.

I am trying to restart a `COMPLETED` Job using the `executionId`. `JobOperator`class is able to restart the batch job even though it is `COMPLETED`. I expect it to throw an exception, as the documentation says. Is this behaviour normal or I am missing anything?

Comment: Can you check if jobId is present in the database used by SpringJob

Comment: yes it is present.

Comment: Every Job has an id and its properties. In that return ExitStatus.COMPLETED or return ExitStatus.FAILED status will be avalible. and you have to place in restartable="true" in xml file or use any annotation and please maintain the final Long restartId = jobOperator.restart(id);
final JobExecution restartExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(restartId);

Answer (score 1):

It's actually depends.

1. You should use `SimpleJobRepository`
2. You should look not for ExitStatus, but for `BatchStatus`. ExitStatus is supplementary result
3. Check that you have identifying parameters for your job

   ```
   if (execution.getJobParameters().getParameters().size() > 0 && (status == BatchStatus.COMPLETED || status == BatchStatus.ABANDONED)) {
     throw new JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException(
                       "A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters=" + jobParameters
                       + ".  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.");
   }
   ```